# Batch TIFF export, QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, export, batch

I try to export 30 different TIFFs from one TIFF and 30 layer of boundaries boxes
using QGIS.

Maybe someone has a hint for me?

Edit1:
I have a map in TIFF format and I need to export 30 different small areas from it in TIFF format.
I tired one by one from File menu, that works but I need it in batch format.
I tried to search some relevant information but I had no success.

Comment: Please be more specific. Explain, what you tried so far, what went wrong, what you expect to achieve exactly, etc.

Comment: I tried single exports from file menu, it's working but I need to export using batch.
I expect to receive 30 tiff files with my own boundary sets that lay in layers/layer/table

Comment: Any what is wrong with `clip raster by layer mask`?

Comment: Are your boundaries represented as polygons in a single vector file?

Comment: Yes they're all in the same layer

Answer (score 1):

This calls for a custom geoprocessing tool:
Alle the features in a shapefile are clipped form the source raster and saved as a separate file with same properties. You can run this script in the qgis python editor after changing the path and filenames.

```
import os, sys
from osgeo import gdal, gdalnumeric, ogr, osr
import numpy as np

# config, all your data is in OUT_FOLDER
OUT_FOLDER= r"c:\tmp"
IN_SHAPE = r"tiles.shp"
IN_RAS =  r"raster.tif"

#open shapefile
source_shape = os.path.join(out_path, IN_SHAPE)
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource = driver.Open(source_shape, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

# open raster
raster_path = os.path.join(OUT_FOLDER, IN_RAS)
print raster_path

srcImage = gdal.Open(raster_path)

# create the spatial reference of source raster
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(srcImage.GetProjectionRef())

# geotransform info
gt = srcImage.GetGeoTransform()
rb = srcImage.GetRasterBand(1)
gdal_datatype = rb.DataType
src_ds_nd = rb.GetNoDataValue()

# Get raster georeference info
xOrigin, yOrigin, pixelWidth, pixelHeight = gt[0], gt[3], gt[1], gt[5]
cellsize = pixelWidth

for feature in layer:
    n = 0
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    name = feature.GetField("name")
    env = geom.GetEnvelope()
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = env[0], env[2], env[1], env[3]

    minX = round(min_x / cellsize, 0) * cellsize
    maxX = round(max_x / cellsize, 0) * cellsize 
    minY = round(min_y / cellsize, 0) * cellsize
    maxY = round(max_y / cellsize) * cellsize 

    ncol = int((maxX - minX) / cellsize)
    nrow= int((maxY - minY) / cellsize)

    tmp_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', ncol, nrow, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

    tmp_ds.SetGeoTransform((
        minX, cellsize, 0,
        maxY, 0, -cellsize,
    ))

    #  Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    dsmem = driver.CreateDataSource("/vsimem/temporarely.shp")
    l_out_mem = dsmem.CreateLayer("memlayer", srs, ogr.wkbPolygon)
       # Add an ID field
    idField = ogr.FieldDefn("id", ogr.OFTInteger)
    l_out_mem.CreateField(idField)

    # Create the feature and set values
    featureDefn = l_out_mem.GetLayerDefn()
    out_feature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
    out_feature.SetField("id", 1)
    out_feature.SetGeometry(geom.Clone())
    l_out_mem.CreateFeature(out_feature)

 # burn value 1 to new raster    
    tmp_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(tmp_ds, [1], l_out_mem, burn_values=[1])

    dsmem = None
    # clip same extent from srcImage
    cellX = int((minX - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
    cellY = int((yOrigin - maxY) / -pixelHeight)

    nparr = rb.ReadAsArray(cellX, cellY, ncol, nrow)


     # mask nieuwe array met rasterized layer
    bandmask = tmp_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    datamask = bandmask.ReadAsArray(0, 0, ncol, nrow).astype(np.float)
    datamask[datamask == 0] = 'nan'

    # Mask zone of raster
    if (nparr is not None):
        zonedata = nparr * datamask
        zonedata[zonedata == src_ds_nd] = 'nan'
        n = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(zonedata))

    if (nparr is None or n < 1) :
        QMessageBox.information(None, "No data is found in feature: "+name,"")
        continue

        # negeer NoData
    zonedata = zonedata.astype(np.float)
    zonedata[zonedata == src_ds_nd] = 'nan'

        # write the clipped raster to fiel    
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(os.path.join(OUT_FOLDER, name+'.tif'), nkol, nrij, 1, gdal_datatype)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((minX, cellsize, 0, maxY, 0, -cellsize, ))

    # Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    target_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
    outBand = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

    # write the data
    outBand.WriteArray(zonedata, 0, 0)
    outBand.FlushCache()
    outBand.SetNoDataValue(-9999)
    target_ds = None
    outBand = None
```